# What's wrong with my UNION SELECT

Tags: sql, mysql, union

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(SELECT Campus_ID AS A_Campus, * FROM A_Campuses
UNION
SELECT Campus_ID AS H_Campus, * FROM H_Campuses
UNION
SELECT Campus_ID AS B_Campus, * FROM B_Campuses)
ORDER BY Campus_Name ASC
```

It gives the sql error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near '* FROM A_Campuses UNION
>   SELECT Campus_ID AS H_Campus, * FROM
>   H_Campuses' at line 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Step 1

You have two syntax errors

1. not aliasing the derived table.
2. `*` cannot be used AFTER a column name, unless you alias the source table

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(SELECT Campus_ID AS A_Campus, A.* FROM A_Campuses A
UNION
SELECT Campus_ID AS H_Campus, H.* FROM H_Campuses H
UNION
SELECT Campus_ID AS B_Campus, B.* FROM B_Campuses B) AS X
ORDER BY Campus_Name ASC
```

#### Step 2

But as Phil points out, since you are sub-querying only to do an order by, there is no need to subquery at all.  ORDER BY applies to the entire UNION-ed result.

```
SELECT Campus_ID AS A_Campus, A.* FROM A_Campuses A
UNION
SELECT Campus_ID AS H_Campus, H.* FROM H_Campuses H
UNION
SELECT Campus_ID AS B_Campus, B.* FROM B_Campuses B
ORDER BY Campus_Name ASC
```

#### Step 3

The next thing to point out is that A_, H_ and B_ must ALL have compatible structures for the UNION to align properly.  It is also worth mentioning that aliasing Campus_ID as different column names has no value.  The column names of the resultant result of a UNION is the FIRST name encountered across the UNION parts - in this case all the column names will come from A_Campuses, as well as the additional column A_Campus.  In actual fact, you will have two columns `A_Campus` and `Campus_ID` which will always hold **EXACTLY** the same values.  What you probably wanted was to indicate the SOURCE of the data: *(notice that I have not even bothered to alias the columns for the 2nd and 3rd parts of the UNION)*

```
SELECT 'A' AS Source, A.* FROM A_Campuses A
UNION ALL
SELECT 'H', H.* FROM H_Campuses H
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', B.* FROM B_Campuses B
ORDER BY Campus_Name ASC
```

#### Note

For performance reasons, use UNION ALL instead of UNION, which performs a DISTINCT against the final result.  If you had duplicate `Campus_ID` across different tables, as well as exactly the same record data, UNION results in one of them being removed, whereas `UNION ALL` keeps both (or all 3) copies.  Given the addition of the Source column, this is not a possibility, so using `UNION ALL` will result in a faster query.

Answer (score 1):

The columns in each branch of the UNION normally need the same name, or will end up with a single name.  Also, a sub-select needs an alias (the 'AS C' below), at least in standard SQL; even if you don't mention the alias anywhere else in the query, as below.

I think what you're after is likely:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT "A" AS Campus_ID, * FROM A_Campuses
        UNION
        SELECT "H" AS Campus_ID, * FROM H_Campuses
        UNION
        SELECT "B" AS Campus_ID, * FROM B_Campuses) AS C
 ORDER BY Campus_Name ASC
```

Comment: Your code gives the error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM A_Campuses
        UNION
        SELECT "H" AS Campus_ID, * FROM H_Camp' at line 2

Comment: if you read the error message, it is complaining about the `*`. It hasn't even reached the stage of `"each derived table must have an alias"`

Comment: @Richard: The DBMS I mostly work with isn't as fussy about the use of '`*`' as it seems MySQL is.  It's funny; every SQL database has its own quirky differences from the others, and it is hard to know all the quirks of all the DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps more parenthesis are needed

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
  (SELECT Campus_ID AS A_Campus, * FROM A_Campuses)
  UNION
  (SELECT Campus_ID AS H_Campus, * FROM H_Campuses)
  UNION
  (SELECT Campus_ID AS B_Campus, * FROM B_Campuses)
)
ORDER BY Campus_Name ASC
```

Also can you UNION with different column names like that? You might need a fake A_Campus and B_Campus in the H_Campus subquery to get identical columns.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't how you write a union query.

Any `ORDER BY` clause applies to the union so you don't need to sub-query it. Also, you should aim to have the same column names and aliases across all parts of the union. Your `A_Campus`, `H_Campus` and `B_Campus` aliases will be lost (not sure which one will win out). For example

```
SELECT Campus_ID, Campus_Name FROM A_Campuses
UNION
SELECT Campus_ID, Campus_Name FROM H_Campuses
UNION
SELECT Campus_ID, Campus_Name FROM B_Campuses
ORDER BY Campus_Name ASC
```

I'd also refrain from using `SELECT *` in a union as you need to be specific about what you're selecting.

Comment: `(not sure which one will win out)` The first one.